# Creating a Parse class to handle parsing of file being read in

Tags: c#, class, parsing

I wrote a parse class trying to handle parsing the data from a string array into it's appropriate value.  I am trying to test this program to see if it will print out the value parse.open, and it is not.  It is printing up 0's for the moment (which isn't accurate), until i could figure out why it's not showing what I need.

```
while (!r.EndOfStream)
{
    ParseFileRead parse = new ParseFileRead();
    string line = r.ReadLine();

    //Send this to Parse class
    string [] values = line.Split(',');
    //parse records
    Console.WriteLine(values[6]); //This is printing the accurate value for parse.open

    ParseFileRead.Parse(values);
    Console.WriteLine(parse.open); //This is not printing the accurate value
}
Console.Read();
vWriteFile.Close();
```

And here is my ParseFileRead class:

```
public class ParseFileRead
{

    public int open { get; set; }
    public int buy { get; set; }
    public int sell { get; set; }
    public double settleMM { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
    public string underlying { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }

    public static void Parse(string[] arr)
    {
        ParseFileRead parse = new ParseFileRead();
        parse.account = arr[0];
        parse.underlying = arr[12];
        parse.symbol = arr[1];
        parse.open = Convert.ToInt32(arr[6]);
        parse.buy = Convert.ToInt32(arr[7]);
        parse.sell = Convert.ToInt32(arr[8]);
        parse.settleMM = Convert.ToDouble(arr[10]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does values[6] print? maybe an issue with converting to an integer. the first print statement (the one that works) is not being converted

Comment: you are recreating the wheel.  There are gobs of parsers around.  NET even has one: `TextFieldParser`

Comment: I know I am recreating the wheel but it is an assignment to do it this way.

@mosca125, the value is 8, when it is printing 0 when I call parse.open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually correct.

The default value for an uninitialized `int` is 0.

You are creating a new instance of your `ParseFileRead` class which will have a value of 0 for open.  You then check your parsed value to make sure it's reading in correctly using `Console.WriteLine(values[6]);`.

Next, you try to parse your values using the `Parse` function of your `ParseFileRead` class; which is a void function so it has no return value.

Inside your `Parse` function you have: `ParseFileRead parse = new ParseFileRead();` which creates yet another new instance of your class with a value of 0 for `open`.  This particular instance is never used anywhere and is not the same as the values of the properties created with your initial instance of `ParseFileRead`

If you put a `Console.Write` in your `Parse` function, I'm sure that you will see it being parsed correctly.

So you have 2 options:

1. Set the properties of your `ParseFileRead` inside the `Parse` class without creating a new instance of `ParseFileRead`
2. Return the newly created `ParseFileRead` instance out of your `Parse` function.

Or a 3rd Option, which is probably best as suggested by Plutonix:

```
/*Parse class*/
public class ParseFileRead
{

    public int open { get; set; }
    public int buy { get; set; }
    public int sell { get; set; }
    public double settleMM { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
    public string underlying { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }

    public ParseFileRead(string[] arr)
    {
        this.account = arr[0];
        this.underlying = arr[12];
        this.symbol = arr[1];
        this.open = Convert.ToInt32(arr[6]);
        this.buy = Convert.ToInt32(arr[7]);
        this.sell = Convert.ToInt32(arr[8]);
        this.settleMM = Convert.ToDouble(arr[10]);
    }
}

/*Parsing code*/

 while (!r.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = r.ReadLine();

        //Send this to Parse class
        string [] values = line.Split(',');
        //parse records
        Console.WriteLine(values[6]); //This is printing the accurate value for parse.open

        ParseFileRead parse = new ParseFileRead(values);
        Console.WriteLine(parse.open); //This is not printing the accurate value


    }
```

Comment: option 3) Change Parse to be a constructor which seeds the values from the array  (omitting the `new` of course)

Comment: @Plutonix That's actually the best option, not sure why I didn't think of that first.